# switch statement will not equate zero?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the following function that works properly, except for when you use the input value of 0. I tried searching around to see if the 0 is equated as a NULL or if I'm doing something wrong.

When a zero is input, it outputs advanced which is greater than 20. Can anyone explain? Thanks

I plan on making the switch equate 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41+ but for this example i am just using two scenarios. Thanks

**EDIT I do want values when its 20 :)

```
function strengthPlan( $data ) {

    $data = ( int ) $data;
    switch( $data ) {
        case( $data <= 19 ):
            $result = 'standard strength';
            break;
        case( $data >= 20 ):
            $result = 'advanced strength';
            break;
    }
    return $result;

}

echo strengthPlan( 0 );
```

Comment: Your understanding of the switch statement is wrong!

Comment: What should happen for a length *exactly* 20? A PHP notice certainly not: *Undefined variable: result*!

Comment: @Cicada can you please explain? I want to understand it properly, thanks

Comment: @Drewdin: http://php.net/switch

Comment: Just in case you did it by accident - your code now doesn't return anything for `19` either.

Comment: @pimvdb, thanks! i just updated it!

Comment: @Drewdin: Great! I'm sorry for nitpicking though but it's `>=` not `=>`. :)

Comment: @pimvdb no nitpicking at all, i appreciate the help! i should have realized that when i was writing it

Comment: @Drewdin: But the `<=` was correct. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. Switch statements are checking for equality. Your code is checking whether `$data` is equal to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
 case( $data < 20 ):
```

will evaluate to:

```
 case( TRUE ):
```

because `0 < 20`.

Since `0` is not equal to `TRUE` but to `FALSE` (after conversion), the second case is run.

Basically, you cannot use `switch case` for `<` or `>` but only for `==`.

Comment: I thought that the switch evaluates the input verse each case, so for instance if I input 6 and (6 < 20) is true than that case would be selected. Should i stay away from using cases in this way? Thanks

Comment: @Drewdin: It 'accidentally' works because any number will be converted to `TRUE`, except `0` because that number 'isn't anything' if you know what I mean. So in other cases than `0`, it is always executing the `TRUE` case, which is also what you expect. I would use the `? :` operator though, as posted by @Jonah.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stay away from using switch statements that way. I was going to break down the switch to many values but for this example i only used two. What would you reccommend for values 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41+. Thanks

Comment: @Drewdin: What about classical `if` statements. I'd say that's the clearest way and also the most maintainable. Note that you can use the `return` 'trick' as returning will stop premarurely: http://codepad.org/tpJYmFTa.

Comment: @Drewdin: see the change to my answer for the answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how switch statements.  They compare the case to the value you provide to `switch`.  Here's what you should do instead:

```
function strengthPlan($length) {
    return $length >= 20 ? 'advanced strength' : 'standard strength';
}
```

If you're planning on using more conditions, then use an `if...elseif` statement as follows:

```
function strengthPlan($length) {
    if     ($length <  5) return 'micro strength';
    elseif ($length < 10) return 'tiny strength';
    elseif ($length < 15) return 'small strength';
    elseif ($length < 20) return 'standard strength';
    elseif ($length < 30) return 'advanced strength';
    else                  return 'super strength!!!!!';
}
```

It will trickle down each condition until it hits a number that it is within.  Alternatively, you can use sort of a lookup table style like this:

```
function strengthPlan($length) {
    $plans = array(
        1            => 'super strength!!!!!',
        $length < 30 => 'advanced strength',
        $length < 20 => 'standard strength',
        $length < 15 => 'small strength',
        $length < 10 => 'tiny strength',
        $length < 5  => 'micro strength',
    );
    return $plans[1];
}
```

There was a discussion about this here: http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=113253

Comment: +1 Agreed; misuse of a switch statement when a one-liner ternary operator fits the bill.

Comment: +1 if I could (vote limit reached), but for the edge case `20` this is returning 'standard strength' while the original code didn't.

Comment: @pimvdb The original didn't return _anything_ ;) But I'll add that anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Jonah: I'm sorry to day but this doesn't have the same result, either :) But I guess the OP doesn't want the function to return nothing when `== 20` anyway. +1 tomorrow :o)

Comment: @pimvdb: I see what you mean, I thought you were saying it should return `advanced strength` instead of `standard strength`, but you were meant that it should return nothing.  But he clearly doesn't want to return nothing if it's exactly 20.

Answer (score 0):

Using switch in this case is wrong

Use this one

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b4053.php

```
<?php 
function strengthPlan( $data ) { 
    return ($data > 20) ? 'advanced strenght' : 'standard strenght'; 
} 

echo strengthPlan( 0 );
```